# How could I generate a X509 from a pem file?

Tags: openssl

I know there is some ways to save a pem file from a X509 certificate, like

```
PEM_write_X509(
        f,   /* write the certificate to the file we've opened */
        ce /* our certificate */
);
```

Could I generate a X509 by a pem file?

Answer (score 0):

There is the opposite to PEM_write_X509 called [PEM_read_X509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PEM_read_X509.html).

```
 X509 *x = NULL;

 if (!PEM_read_bio_X509(bp, &x, 0, NULL))
     /* Error */
```